# Security of sending information to stdout

Tags: gnupg

By default, something like `gpg -d file.gpg` sends it's output to stdout. What happens to input that is sent to stdout? Is it possible to recover this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, `stdout` is just a unix pipe.  Essentially, it can keep some amount of the data in memory, and then blocks on input until the other end of the pipe is read from.  Often, this is the user's shell, which will read from the pipe and print to the user's terminal (or pseudo-terminal).  Of course, it can also be redirected to file output or to another program.

In the normal case, where the output is displayed on the user's terminal, the data is of course in memory, so if the memory is swapped to disk, it might be recoverable.  Also, if you have the running system, it might be possible to recover in-memory if it hasn't been overwritten yet.